# Wildcard subdomains showing " X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" for ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

I am working wildcard subdomains. While I goto a subdomain (username.domain.com)  ajax requests are not working. I got following error on console:

> Failed to load ajaxpage.php: Request header field X-Requested-With is
>   not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in response.

Can any help me how to solve this error.

Comment: Please provide information about your server application (`ajaxpage.php`). Where and how do you write your HTTP headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax request may contain a header line like `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. Any non-standard headers are forbidden by default.

You may need to add to your `ajaxpage.php` the header line to allow this extra header:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
```

Please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers